# Is there a value of $\alpha$ such that $2\tan\alpha=-\sqrt{2}\sin\alpha?$

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a value of $\alpha$ such that $2\tan\alpha=-\sqrt{2}\sin\alpha?$

We have $2\tan\alpha=-\sqrt{2}\sin\alpha \iff 2\cdot\dfrac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}=-\sqrt{2}\sin\alpha.$ If we divide by $\sin\alpha$, we'll get $2=-\sqrt{2}\cos\alpha,$ or $\cos\alpha=-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt2}=-\sqrt{2}$ which isn't in the inverval $\left[-1;+1\right].$ So there isn't a value of $\alpha$ such that  $2\tan\alpha=-\sqrt{2}\sin\alpha$. Are we allowed to divide by $\sin\alpha$ and should I see what's going on when $\sin\alpha=0?$

Comment: There are infinite values of alpha $0,\pi,2\pi....$

Comment: While as noted you do need to see what's going on in the cases where $\sin \alpha=0$, your argument works fine in the other cases and shows that those are the only possible $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot divide by $\sin\alpha$ if $\sin\alpha=0$. Any solution of $\sin\alpha=0$ is a solution of $2\tan\alpha=-\sqrt{2}\sin\alpha$, since both sides are then zero.

Comment: Thank you! When $\sin\alpha=0?$

Comment: You're welcome! Since $\sin\alpha=0$, $\alpha$ must be an integer multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why is that. I am trying to imagine the unit circle. Sine corresponds to the 2nd coordinate. It's $0$ only on the x-axis, right?

Comment: Yes, the $y$-coordinate is zero if the angle is $0,\pi,2\pi$. Larger angles correspond to going round the circle multiple times and negative angles correspond to going round the circle clockwise.